# What do you call a quote from an article that is displayed prominently in the article itself?

Tags: terminology

When you're reading an article, often you'll see a quote from the very same article written in large, bold letters. I guess it's supposed to entice skimmers to read it or some such. What is that called?

Comment: @Kris Couldn't find it ... can you link the duplicate question?

Comment: This should help: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/what-is-the-name-of-the-technique-where-an-article-quotes-itself-in-large-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two of the main terms for this are *[callout](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callout)* and *[pull quote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull-quote)*, the former meaning "A pull quote: an excerpt from an article (such as in a news magazine) that is duplicated in a large font alongside the article so as to grab a reader's attention and indicate the article's topic", and the latter "In newspaper and magazine publishing, a brief excerpt drawn from an article and used out of context."

Related terms (but not such as the question asks for) include *[sidebar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidebar)*, "a short news story printed alongside a larger one" or "information placed at the side of a webpage"; *[hook](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hook)* in the sense "A brief, punchy opening statement intended to draw the reader or viewer into a book or play"; and *[blurb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blurb)*, "A short description of a book, film, musical work, or other product written and used for promotional purposes."  Like callouts, box quotes, or pull quotes, these items may appear in large bright type to attract attention.

Comment: In your first sentence did you mean latter or former? You say "pull quote" when the former is "callout".

Comment: In that sentence, 'former' refers to  *callout* and 'latter' to *pull quote*.  Sense #3 from the cited https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callout definition of  *callout* says, "A pull quote: an excerpt from an article (such as in a news magazine) that is duplicated in a large font alongside the article so as to grab a reader's attention and indicate the article's topic."  That is, I mentioned two main terms (with links to definitions) and then in the same order quoted definitions of the two terms.