# A word for a title and description

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for a title and short paragraph? for example:

> ## Lorem ipsum
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
>   sagittis dictum nisl. Duis ac dapibus diam. Maecenas porta non dolor
>   in commodo. Aliquam feugiat nisl non enim vulputate semper. Cras
>   imperdiet aliquet eros sed fermentum. Etiam vitae arcu ac lacus
>   viverra iaculis ut cursus magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit.

This could be at the start of a page or multiple times one under the other.
Is there a word that defines this?

Comment: What is the purpose/context of the text? I might call it an *abstract* if it describes a written work, or possibly a [*blurb*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blurb) in several other contexts.

Comment: For example a website where you have a list of blog posts, a title and bit of text, or at the top of a page (like an introduction) but I was after a word that encompasses both the title and paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, some portions of answers to previous and related questions ([What do you call a quote from an article that is displayed prominently in the article itself?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/54861) and [What are footnotes called when they aren’t in the footer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96409)) are included below.

> Two of the main terms for [a prominently displayed quote] are *[callout](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callout)* and *[pull quote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull-quote)*, the former meaning “A pull quote: an excerpt from an article (such as in a news magazine) that is duplicated in a large font alongside the article so as to grab a reader’s attention and indicate the article’s topic”, and the latter “In newspaper and magazine publishing, a brief excerpt drawn from an article and used out of context.”
>
> Related terms [...] include *[sidebar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidebar)*, “a short news story printed alongside a larger one” or “information placed at the side of a webpage”; *[hook](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hook)* in the sense “A brief, punchy opening statement intended to draw the reader or viewer into a book or play”; and *[blurb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blurb)*, “A short description of a book, film, musical work, or other product written and used for promotional purposes.”  Like callouts, box quotes, or pull quotes, these items may appear in large bright type to attract attention. [jwpat7]

> *[Sidenotes](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidenote)* is a common term used to denote the notes, trivia or anything interesting noted by the author on the sidelines of pages of his book. [Mohit]
>
> Marginalia, see Wikipedia: [Marginalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginalia) or margin note. [Dohn Joe]
>
> The terms *marginal notes*, *marginal markings*, *graffiti*, and *graffito* are used to refer to the numerous small sidebars in italics within ***Concrete Mathematics*** by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. [jwpat7]
>
> You might use the word **annotations** to describe explanatory text or comments found on the margins of literary works and diagrams. [KeyBrd Basher]

Comment: Hmm, I think callout is what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using "Introduction" which could apply to both heading and body text.

Comment: Only if it's at the start of the piece, which is not apparent fromn the question.