# Is there a term for an offset quote that is only quoting the body of the text?

Tags: quotations, typography, flow

A trend in many magazine-style articles is to take a quote from the body of the article and place it in its own blockquote or other special formatting, then place it somewhere irrelevant in the flow of the document.

> #### SOME NON-SEQUITUR NONSENSE

Is there a name for this practice? It can occasionally add some context as an image caption, but most of the time it simply breaks the flow of reading with some non-sequitur nonsense, as above.

In all honesty, the whole reason I want a name for this is so that I can complain about it more effectively. I work at a publishing company, and I've seen this practice sneak into a few of our books. In addition, it's quite common in professional blogs such as [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2014/2/18/5412636/this-machine-kills-trolls-how-wikipedia-robots-snuff-out-vandalism), witness the obnoxious orange text splattered throughout.

Comment: I call them splash quotes, although I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in my [answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54869/11433), terms   *callout*, *pull quote*, *sidebar*, *hook*, and *blurb* are names of various forms of emphasized quotes that accompany magazine articles.  Also see  [What is the name of the technique where an article quotes itself in large text?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/15029), which quotes from [desktoppub.about.com](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/glossary/g/Pull-Quote.htm) as follows.

> Used to attract attention, especially in long articles, a **pull-quote** is a small selection of text pulled out and quoted in a larger typeface or using some other formatting distinct from the rest of the article. A pull-quote may be framed by rules, placed within the article, span multiple columns, or be placed in an empty column near the article.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I tried searching this on the site, but it's dashed hard to search for without knowing the term already.

Comment: In my shop we call them *callouts*, but most of our work is video or powerpoint rather print.